# How to resolve problem with es_extended Fivem

Tags: lua, fivem, grand-theft-auto

i have a problem with es_extended.

I have this error : SCRIPT ERROR: @es_extended/client/functions.lua:554: bad argument #1 to 'vector3' (invalid vector type)

the link of the es_extended that I downloaded :
https://github.com/esx-framework/esx_core/tree/main/%5Bcore%5D/es_extended

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The errored line is `coords = vector3(coords.x, coords.y, coords.z)`  Probably `coords` is not a 3D vector.